# Sum of Values in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to do Sum of the Values in My Kendo Grid to Form its Total,

For that I am using a Kendo Grid Like,

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.SupplementViewModel>()
                        .Name("Supplement")
                        .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:20px; " })
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.SupplementID).Hidden(true);

                            columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title("Description").Width(15);

                            columns.Bound(p => p.Nett).Title("Nett").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class="Currency"});
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Tax).Title("Tax").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Currency" });
                            columns.Bound(p => p.GST_VAT).Title("GST_VAT").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Currency" });
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ServiceTax).Title("ServiceTax").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Currency" });
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ServiceFee).Title("ServiceFee").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Currency" });
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Total).Title("Total").Width(15).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Currency" });


                        })
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                        .Navigatable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(200))
                        .Scrollable()
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Batch(true)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                            .Model(model =>{
                                model.Id(p => p.ProductTypeCode);
                            })
                            .Create("Editing_Create", "Grid")

                            .Update("Editing_Update", "Grid")
                            .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Grid")
                            )
                )
```

Scenario is  something Like this::
[image]

I want to Show the Sum of Values in "Total" depends on there changing,
How can It be done? Please help me on this.

Comment: Use kendo grid aggregates..http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/aggregates.html

Comment: But aggregate is use for aggregate of particular column
and in My scenario I want the Sum of all columns in Total.

Comment: I guess you need the sum of the row (not the column). So `Sum = Total = SUM(Nett, Tax, GST_VAT...) `. If this is the case, you can do the summation from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got something that I am using in my scenario, & its done manually using javascript::

```
  $("#Supplement").on('change', '.Currency > input[type="text"]', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var temp = $(this).val();

        var nett = parseFloat(row.find('input')[2].value);
        var tax = parseFloat(row.find('input')[3].value);
        var gst_vat = parseFloat(row.find('input')[4].value);
        var servicetax = parseFloat(row.find('input')[5].value);
        var servicefee = parseFloat(row.find('input')[6].value);
        var total = nett + tax + gst_vat + servicetax + servicefee;
        row.find('.TotalCurrency ')[0].textContent = total;

    });
```

If anyone having any new solution then please suggest, I will try to implement that in my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregates as shown in this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/aggregates.html

There are two kinds of aggregate - ones applied during grouping and ones applied for the whole grid. Here is how to define the latter:

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.UnitsInStock).Min().Max().Count();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.UnitsOnOrder).Average();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ProductName).Count();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.UnitPrice).Sum();
        })
```

Comment: Yes I know this Example But My scenario is different from that,
Please Suggest me in My scenario that what should I do in above code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need the `summation of each row`. You can do this in your controller.

```
Total = Nett + Tax + GST_VAT...
```

Or in the view model

```
public int Total
{
    get
    {
        return this.Nett + this.Tax;
    }
}
```

If you want the summation of each column, use aggregate as described by `Atanas Korchev`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that given the requirement for client-side update of the Total your solution is a viable one.

I would suggest that you do not fetch or update the cell data directly (e.g. 
`var tax = parseFloat(row.find('input')[3].value`
);

Instead get the value using the grid client-side API. Namely:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
var data = grid.dataItem(row);
tax = data.tax;
```

See documentation of dataItem [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem).